# removing room dividing wall?

Tags: ceiling, joists, remodeling, load

I have a colonial which I would like to extend the kitchen into what is now a living room, the wall does run perpendicular which usually would indicate that this is load bearing, but also the joists in the living room run the opposite way as the kitchen, so does this mean that the kitchen joists that are attached to the living room joist takes the load on that single 2x10? could I just add joists hangers to each kitchen joist attached to the living room joist, and but up another 2x10(nail together) against the joist the kitchen joists are attached to, creating additional support.

Added 2 more photos, So I opened the ceiling up more on the living room side, the joists do run opposite of the kitchen, and there were TWO!! joists next to each other, which is pretty much what I was going to do if I removed the wall anyways, hmm does this mean anything to you guys?
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Seeing there is probably a second floor above and the wall is near the end of the joists holding it up, I would not be quick to remove it.  This is something to have a professional engineer have a look at and give safe ideas.  Will probably need a beam to replace the wall at least.

Comment: Unless the red arrow pointed wood is sistered, I wouldn't call it a major beam, your kitchen wall does take some load, although it was already weakened by the drain pipe and missing studs. I would call an engineer or architect to clear the situation.

Comment: Are you 100% certain that what you think is a joist running perpendicular to the kitchen joists isn't just blocking between them?

Answer (score 2):

Yes that wall has the appearance of being a bearing wall:

- the header above the doorway is solid
- joists terminate on top of the wall, especially with no hangers to the other joist

That first living room joist as it stands now is almost certainly not up to the task of carrying the loads of all these kitchen joists. That said, all hope is not lost -- it'll just be a more involved effort to get the load transfer worked out. Doubling or tripling the first living room joist may be necessary. Use of an LVL (laminated veneer lumber, an engineered wood product) could help. Joist hangers will be part of the solution.

It might be possible to do this with "prescriptive methods" in which one uses tables found in the building code and/or tables supplied by the manufacturer in the case of an LVL. You may be able to work out a solution through study of those resources, but it might be a more efficient use of your time to engage an experienced contractor to devise a solution.

The alternative to prescriptive methods is to engage a professional engineer. Don't worry; they're not so expensive as it sounds. The process would likely involve you explaining your goal, the engineer directing which additional areas you'll need to remove drywall to expose the existing structure, and then the engineer could propose details for you to go and build.

Comment: I appreciate the info, as of now I am exposing more of the ceiling in the living room to get a better understanding of how this home was constructed, I have been leaning towards bringing in a structural engineer for a solution, and I believe if it is just adding a LVL beam next to the living room joist(and attaching), then adding joist hangers to the kitchen joists, this should make a fairly inexpensive job, but until I find out more from a professional, the job is on a stand still.

Answer (score 0):

Not only is that wall load bearing but it is honestly the most important interior wall on that floor.   For sure load bearing.   It would need a substantial header and load points on each side.   You are probably looking at from the outside wall to the corner of the bathroom with part of bathroom wall needing to be redone and possibly a pole in the basement (if there is one).